# Dump Sqlite select result to xml

Tags: ios, xml, sqlite

I want to generate structured xml from result of select query.
I tried with FOR XML but its not working .
How i should achieve this

Answer (score 1):

SQLite does not have XML formatting functions.
You have to do this in your code.

Answer (score 0):

If we are using sqlite3 command line tool, we can choose from the
following output modes (from the .help command):

```
.mode MODE ?TABLE?  Set output mode where MODE is one of:
      csv      Comma-separated values
      column   Left-aligned columns.  (See .width)
      html     HTML <table> code
      insert   SQL insert statements for TABLE
      line     One value per line
      list     Values delimited by .separator string
      tabs     Tab-separated values
      tcl      TCL list elements
```

There is a HTML mode, but currently no XML mode.